# How to have an icon next to text on an icon

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to have a button with an icon and text. The icon on the left and text on the right. The following code gives me a button with an icon on top and text on the bottom.

```
<button class="btn-simple2" >
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("Confirmation","Dashboard", new { id = Model.Data.Id })%>" rel="external"          target="_blank" class="ui-icon ui-icon-print">
    </a>Print Confirmation
</button>
```

How can I make them next to each other?? I have looked through the questions this site and that is how I got this far. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, do some thing like that:

css:

```
.btn-simple2 {
    padding-left: 24px;
    background: url(../path/to/image) 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

html:

```
<a class="btn-simple2" 
   href="<%= Url.Action("Confirmation","Dashboard", new { id = Model.Data.Id })%>">
   Print Confirmation
</a>
```

Comment: dear @user1229309, this is the simpliest way to do this.
may take a look on [smashingmagazine](http://smashingmagazine.com)